# Existence of universal arrow from manifolds to forgetful functor of Lie groups

Tags: ct.category-theory, lie-groups, manifolds

Let $M$ be a manifold, and $U$ be the forgetful functor from the category of Lie groups to the category of manifolds. My question is whether there is a universal arrow $(G, i)$ from $M$ to $U$? More precisely, whether there is a Lie group $G$ and a smooth map $i: M \rightarrow U(G)$ such that, for all smooth map $\phi: M \rightarrow U(Q)$, there exists a unique Lie group homomorphism $f: G \rightarrow Q$ with $U(f)\circ i = \phi$?

should we impose any conditions on $\phi$ to make it true?

An intuition to this question may make it interesting is that when we define a smooth structure on a manifold, whether we have identified a "relations" or "connections" between elements of this manifold simultaneously, such that "relations"  take the form of Lie group. When we have a smooth map between manifolds, it transforms or collapses "relations" of one to another, and it collapses one Lie group to another.

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand "An intuition to this question may make it interesting is that when we define a smooth structure on a manifold, whether we have identified a "relations" or "connections" between elements of this manifold simultaneously, such that "relations" take the form of Lie group" can you explain a bit...

Comment: One may think "relations" as actions of a Lie group on the manifold such that connect two elements, ($s(a) = b$ action $s$ connects $a$ and $b$). Such a group is innate to the smooth structure of the manifold.  the relation of this lie group $G$ with manifold $M$ is expressed by smooth map  $i: M \rightarrow U(G)$. Now if we have another manifold $N$ and relation $j: N \rightarrow U(Q)$ then for a smooth map $\phi: M \rightarrow N$ we have map $j \circ \phi: M \rightarrow U(Q)$, then by the question we may have $f: G \rightarrow Q$. btw it is just my vague feeling.

Comment: If one really insists on Lie groups, with finite-dimensional underlying smooth manifolds, then such such a Lie group exists only for 0-dimensional M.  However, if one passes to the category of smooth sets (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+set), then such a generalized Lie group does exist and can be computed by applying the free group functor objectwise to the given representable presheaf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such arrow exists if and only if $Dim(M)=0$. In this case $G$ is the free group $F(M)$, considered as a $0$-dimensional manifold.

If $Dim(M)>0$, you can cook up a smooth map $M\rightarrow {\mathbb R}^n$, such that $\{ \alpha e_k | \alpha \in (-1,1)\}$ is in the image for each standard basis element $e_k$. This means that the corresponding Lie group homomorphism $G\rightarrow {\mathbb R}^n$ must be surjective. Thus, $Dim(G)\geq n$ for each $n$. So $G$ is not a Lie group.

Besides the smooth sets mentioned by Pavlov, you can use the category of Tychonoff topological spaces. There again the usual free group will give you the universal arrow. It is explained, for instance, in Abstract Harmonic Analysis by Hewitt and Ross.

Comment: if $X$ is a topological manifold, the free topological group $F(X)$ over $X$ is also a topological manifold?

Comment: No, it is not. It is a nice topological or smooth space but it is infinite-dimensional in several ways that can be made precise.

Comment: sorry for my question, I intend to ask whether it has a smooth structure, not necessarily has finite dimension.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a smooth structure. It is not going to be a Banach or Frechet manifold but it is a smooth space (see Panov's comment).

Comment: Thanks! It is helpful